# Retrieving operations with parameters from wdsl to UI

Tags: tibco, tibco-gi, tibco-topic

From Tibco Desiner, I couldn't find the way to retrieve operations with parameters from wdsl to UI, can anyone suggest be how to accomplish this with Designer.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what you are trying to achieve? Which activities and/or resources are you having problems with?

Comment: I have a wsdl with 24 operations, each with different set of input and output and trying to design UI (tibco GI), where I should retrieve the list of operations to UI and choose a operation to execute.
As I am new to Tibco couldn't find which palette to use or how to proceed. :(

Comment: You need to use the SOAP and/or Service palettes. Have a look at http://goo.gl/qukr7l to see how to leverage an existing WSDL in TIBCO Designer.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I do have that doc, but got stuck with mapping the elements in process definition can you please show or send me an example

Comment: I suggest you search on Google, some websites explain how to do this (e.g. http://goo.gl/IXeDdG).

Comment: If I find that in google, why will I post this question here..

Comment: Did the link I provided help?

Comment: It is awesome, but it didn't help me